# How do I prevent a re-render of a large list?

Tags: lit-element

I have a 60x30 grid for a game editor and as cells are updated, a new array is created to hold the state.

The problem is that when I update that grid array, this changes the property and it causes `render()` to recreate the grid. This seems almost obvious but then what do my options become?

If this is overly specific, imagine just a huge list of items and you have an immutable array in which one of the items properties must change.

```
 render() { 
    return html`
      ${this.data?.cells.map((row) => {
        return row.map((cell) => {
          return html`<editor-cell .data="${cell}"></editor-cell>`;
        });
      })}
    `;
  }
```

Coincidentally, I had the same problem on Angular with a for loop only it had `trackBy` which used the index or item.id to prevent the recreation of a list of items.  I just accepted the unicorns for that but here it is the same issue.

**Question:**

What am I missing about immutable states here? I totally understand why this is happening in that, its a new array and so lit element just renders what it deems a new array.  I want that, but once the grid has been rendered, I don't understand the separation between rendering and data updates. I'm either missing a key lifecycle understanding, or my approach to state is just totally whack.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`repeat` directive](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/writing-templates#repeating-templates)?

Answer (score 0):

If you update the complete array this change the memory reference and then lit-html has to re-render the whole array because it doesn't know what item changes.

In the lit-html documentation you have a section about [Repeating templates](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/writing-templates#repeating-templates) that explain that very well.

In your case you should use `repeat` directive, that performs efficient updates of lists based on user-supplied keys:

```
render() { 
  return html`
    ${repeat(this.data?.cells, row => row.id,
      row => html`${repeat(row, cell => cell.id,
        cell => html`<editor-cell .data="${cell}"></editor-cell>`
      )}`
    )}
  `;
}
```

Notice the importance of the second argument, that it's the guaranteed unique key for each item.